# Sharing Record with partner users

Tags: apex, customer-community, sharing-rule, apex-managed-sharing, criteria-based-sharing

Let me explain concept first.we have one concept called retail copy like when ever Power partner wants to access any person account which is created by standard users of salesforce.he should do retail copy of that person account (to access the account).
Now, When Powerpartner clicks on retail copy I want to share the records which are associated with person account (records created by standard users) with Powerpartner on clicking of retail copy.what should I do??
Please explain

Comment: Do you use Customer Community or Partner Community? What do you mean by "he should do retail copy of that person account"? What profile settings have you tried and in which respect haven't they worked?

Comment: Hi Felix,we use partner community. Retail copy means getting access of an account for a Partner user.We have one separate profile assigned for partners.